# Output lighter and darker colour variants

Tags: sass

I want to output some utility classes and I can't seem to get the lighter and darker tones of my base color to output both darker and lighter tones. I am new to Scss but this is what I have:

```
$aqua: #00ffff;

$color-map: (
  background-color-aqua-light: ($aqua, background-color, lighten,),
  color-aqua-light: ($aqua, color, lighten),
  background-color-aqua-dark: ($aqua, background-color, darken),
  color-aqua-dark: ($aqua, color, darken)
);

@each $color-class, $colour-variables in $color-map {

  $class-name: nth($color-class, 1);
  $color-name: nth($colour-variables, 1);
  $color-type: nth($colour-variables, 2);
  $color-brightness: nth($colour-variables, 3);


  @for $i from 20 through 100{
    @if $i % 10 == 0{
      $percentage: $i*0.5%;
      .#{$class-name}-#{$i}{
        #{$color-type}: #{$color-brightness}($color-name, $percentage);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're generating the method name in the CSS:

So this SCSS

```
#{$color-type}: #{$color-brightness}($color-name, $percentage);
```

Becomes this CSS

```
.background-color-aqua-light-40 {
  background-color: lighten(#00ffff, 20%);
}
```

To my knowledge, you can't interpolate a SASS method name **and** get SASS to interpret it. *But.* I think you *can* (maybe less elegantly) get around that limitation with the `@if` and `@elseif` rules in your `@for` loop.

```
@for $i from 20 through 100 {
    @if $i % 10 == 0 {
      $percentage: $i*0.5%;
      .#{$class-name}-#{$i} {
        @if ( $color-brightness == lighten ) {
          #{$color-type}: lighten($color-name, $percentage);
        } @elseif ( $color-brightness == darken ) {
          #{$color-type}: darken($color-name, $percentage);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**EDIT:** FWIW, I tested the `@if/@elseif` solution on [sassmeister.com](https://www.sassmeister.com/) and it seems to crank out the CSS you are after.